# customize_preview_init: listening for any changes from Customizer preview area

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer, previews

I know I can listen for specific setting changes from the previewer by adding the following JS to the **`customize_preview_init`** hook:

```
wp.customize( 'setting-ID', function ( value ) {
    value.bind( function( val ) {    
      // things go here
    } );
} );
```

But can I easily listen for *any* changes?  Or a group of changes?  For example, I have a ton of settings that are all named something like: `my_settings[setting_a], my_setting[setting_b]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can bind to the `change` event on the entire `Setting` collection (`wp.customize`) as follows:

```
wp.customize.bind( 'change', function ( setting ) {
    if ( 0 === setting.id.indexOf( 'my_settings[' ) ) {
        doSomethingWithSettingValue( setting.get() );
    }
});
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!  How do I grab the variable from the setting tho?  I've tried: `console.log(wp.customize.value(setting));` but that returns a function `ƒ (){return f.instance.apply(f,arguments)}`

Comment: Use `setting.get()`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WestonRuter, for me you will always be the GRAND MASTER of the Customizer JS API. Correct me if I'm wrong, but `'my_settings['` should be `'my_setting_name'` without `[`. It's what I've tried and worked for me. Thanks again !